# Visual Studio Community, stop inserting spaces

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In VS Community 2017 for mac how do I get the editor to stop inserting spaces?

Example:

```
public string myProperty { get;
```

the space is added automatically when I type `{`.  It ruins my flow and ends up being

```
public string myProperty {  get;
```

Comment: I understand this can be unnerving, but you should really rely on auto reformatting instead of making an effort to write everything perfectly yourself.

Comment: Mehh, I prefer my editors to do nothing.  I write everything perfectly after years of practice.